# Linux tree command errors on opening hidden dirs

Tags: linux, command-line, tree

Why if I use the linux tree command against hidden dirs does it error?

```
$ tree -ad '.ssh'
.ssh [error opening dir]

0 directories
```

but I can see it appears fine when the hidden dir is a subdirectory:

```
$ tree -a test1
test1
├── .hiddendir1
│   └── testfile2
└── testfile1

1 directory, 2 files
$ mv test1/.hiddendir1/ .hiddendir1
$ tree -a test1
test1
└── testfile1

0 directories, 1 file
$ tree -a .hiddendir1/
.hiddendir1/ [error opening dir]

0 directories, 0 files
$ mv .hiddendir1/ test1/
$ tree -a test1
test1
├── .hiddendir1
│   └── testfile2
└── testfile1

1 directory, 2 files
```

[for reference]
I installed tree using

```
sudo snap install tree
```

and snap info tree tells me I have version:

```
installed:   1.8.0+pkg-3fd6
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - per the suggestion, I have flagged this for transfer to Unix and Linux